# Forming a sequence from a Cauchy Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_{n})$ be a Cauchy sequence. Is $c_{n} = (-1)^{n}a_{n}$ also a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: Consider $a_n := 1$  $\forall n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you work in some $\mathbb{R}^n$ space. You probably know that a sequence converges if and only if it is a Cauchy sequence. Hence one can reformulate your question as follow : Does $(-1)^n a_n$ converge if $a_n$ converges ?

The answer is clearly no, for example take the constant sequence $a_n = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is only true if $a_n\to 0$.  Otherwise, no mas.